# which is the proper site to ask a question on MATLAB

Tags: support, site-recommendation

In   engineering.stackexchange.com   I asked  the following question (10K only: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/18035/4916) :

> **Title:**
>   Can be shared and modified the same files of database and files of math formulae by Matlab and by Octave?"
>
> **Text:**
>   "In order to make exercise on conceptual and preliminary aeronautical construction design, I have to create new files and to use and modify old files and databes of MATLAB. Can I make all the same things using opensource software Octave? Can files created by Octave be used with and modified by MATLAB? Can files created by MATLAB be used with and modified by Octave?"

A person wrote:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, once reworded, should go onto StackOverflow or possibly a site dedicated to Octave vs. MATLAB

So, I asked similar question (10K only: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47318857/8948242) on  stackoverflow.com  with the following title and text:

> **Title:**
>   Can be shared and modified the same files of database and files of math formulae by Matlab and by Octave?
>
> **Text:**
>   In order to make exercise on conceptual and preliminary aeronautical construction design, I have to create new files and to use and modify old files and databes of MATLAB. Can I make all the same things using free-software Octave? Can files created by Octave be used with and modified by MATLAB? Can files created by MATLAB be used with and modified by Octave?"

But the question was “closed” with the following explanation:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Then,  can you show me which is the proper site for that question?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not with a topic, but with asking extremely under-specified questions, several at a time. Such questions are not welcome anywhere on Stack Exchange.

These would be answers:

> Can I make all the same things using free-software Octave?

Maybe, maybe not.

> Can files created by Octave be used with and modified by MATLAB?

Sometimes yes, sometimes no.

> Can files created by MATLAB be used with and modified by Octave?

Sometimes yes, sometimes no.

---

Quit your fishing expedition around Stack Exchange and do your own research; then  ask a specific, informed question.